# Comparing a variable against two different values in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is more a question of semantics than anything else.

I'd like to check if a variable is either one of two values. The easiest way of doing this would be:

```
if var == "foo" || var == "bar"
# or
if var == 3     || var == 5
```

But this doesn't feel very DRY to me. I know I can use `String.match()`, but that doesn't work for non-string variables and is three times slower.

Is there a better way of checking a variable against two values?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put all values into an array and then it should be easy.

```
%w[foo bar].include?('foo') # => true

[3,5].include?(3) # => true
```

Comment: Missing the if statement... if(%w[foo bar].include?(var))

Comment: Yeah, I realized I could do this almost as soon as I posted the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `case` statement seems to do what you want.

```
case var
  when "foo", "bar" then case1()
end

case var
  when 3, 5 then case2()
end
```

The array-based methods seem likely to be slower than this.

Comment: case notation just wraps around using `#===` for each when statement, so this will be the same as `if ["foo", "bar"] === var then case1(); elsif [3,5] === var then case2(); end`

Comment: I tried to test the speed of this vs. equivalent `.include?` method, and `case` was slightly faster.  Not enough to make a compelling argument, though.

Comment: My problem with this approach that it feels clunkier than the one-line `if [1,2].include?(1)`. I agree that `case` works very well as a replacement for multiple if and elsif statements, but not for something simple like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
%W(foo bar baz).include? var
```

Or:

```
[3, 5].include? var
```